# The items in my shopping cart disappear when I navigate to another page on my site

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Legenda WordPress theme
The items in my shopping cart disappear when I navigate to another page on my site, then back to my shop page. Here are the steps to demonstrate:

1. Go to http://www.carathut.com
2. Select any item to add to cart, make sure it is showing in your cart
3. Navigate to any other page and now the cart shows as being empty and if go to the cart again it will show the items that you have put to cart.

It does this when using all browsers.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I've been going bonkers trying to fix this.

Comment: do you set the cookies? did you made any extensions to the theme, plugin for shopping?

Comment: This question is too general I think